# Android Key Invalidation when Fingerprints removed

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, fingerprint

I'm testing on a Google Pixel device on 7.1.1 and finding that my Private Key isn't being invalidated when all fingerprints are removed from the device. I've tested using a single symmetric SecretKey as per the demo app and that worked as expected, however using an asymmetric key pair only throws a `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` when new prints are enrolled, and not when they are all deleted.

What's more, if I then enrol a new fingerprint, then show my fingerprint dialog and successfully scan my fingerprint authenticating the `Cipher` object, when I then call `doFinal()` on the `Cipher` object it throws a `KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated`. If I then try to initialise the Cipher object again after the `KeyStoreException` then I get the invalidated exception as required.

I did test on a Samsung S7 using 6.0.1 and that works correctly, with the `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` being thrown when the prints are all removed. I have found in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243239/android-fingerprint-api-and-private-public-keys) that someone else had trouble with a Nexus (OS version wasn't mentioned), possibly related? Could there be a bug with certain combinations of devices/OS not invalidating particular keys?

It would seem that:

1. On Pixel or 7.1.1 devices, the PrivateKey is not invalidated when all fingerprints are removed.
2. If enrolling new prints after previously removing all of them, the PrivateKey can't be used to decrypt data, however it only gets invalidated after you try to use it.

Is there a way to manually invalidate a key via the keystore or something when I detect that a user has registered for fingerprints in my app before but there are now no fingerprints enrolled on the device as a bit of failsafe?

UPDATE: showing key generation at request.

```
mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
            new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(getKeyName(), KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
                        .build());
        mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: Have you used `setUserAuthenticationRequired` and `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds`? Show your code.

Comment: Yes I am using `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)`, not using a validity duration though as I want to authorise each use of the key.

Comment: Hi, I've exactly the same problem. Were you able to solve it? Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey @Venator85, unfortunately not. Like I mention in the post, I think its a bug with Android and that particular combination of key.

Comment: Even Pixel running in Android 8.0 also giving me same issue. Is any work around there?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** This it would seem is partly related to [Google Issue 227919](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227919). Comment in Feb/17 Says a fix was put in latest N version but I can still reproduce like others.

If you have this issue, please star Google issue so it gets more attention.