# Removal of Fingerprint not triggering InvalidKeyException for Fingerprnt Authentication

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am facing issue with Fingerprint authentication, actually, I have integrated Fingerprint Authentication in my app and working fine except one case.

I have set up two Fingerprint in my device, after initializing `KeyGenerator` with Fingerprint KEY, I have removed one Fingerprint from device and come back to my app and performing Fingerprint Auth it is working fine. I don't know why it is not triggering `InvalidKeyException` as like adding Fingerprint works. **Is this expected behavior or any bug with OS?**

Device Details are below,

`Device : Pixel`

`OS: Android 8.0`

Code of my implementation follows,

```
protected void generateKey() {
       try {
           keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
       try {
           keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
       }


       try {
           keyStore.load(null);
           keyGenerator.init(new
                   KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                   KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                           KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                   .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                   .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                   .setEncryptionPaddings(
                           KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                   .build());
           keyGenerator.generateKey();
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
               InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
               | CertificateException | IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }

 public boolean cipherInit() {
       try {
           cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
       }


       try {
           keyStore.load(null);
           SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                   null);
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
           return true;
       } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
           return false;
       } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
       }
   }
}
```

I have already tried with few posts([How to detect the removal fingerprint in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544577/how-to-detect-the-removal-fingerprint-in-android), [Android Fingerprint API and Private/Public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243239/android-fingerprint-api-and-private-public-keys), [Android Key Invalidation when Fingerprints removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359337/android-key-invalidation-when-fingerprints-removed)), nothing helped me to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not strictly tied to fingerprints. All it has that is somewhat related is:

```
setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
```

That says that the key that you are creating in the `AndroidKeyStore` requires user authentication. It does not say anything about fingerprints.

If the user has fingerprints registered, the user could use a fingerprint to authenticate for the purposes of using this key. That would be for any fingerprint registered by the user, and in your case, you still have a registered fingerprint (even after the user removed the second fingerprint). Also, the user does not have to use a fingerprint to authenticate — they could use their passphrase, PIN, or pattern, if they choose.

> Is this expected behavior or any bug with OS?

This is expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for the brief detail and is there any way to identify the Fingerprint deletion?

Comment: @SathishKumar: I do not think so.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: _"Also, the user does not have to use a fingerprint to authenticate — they could use their passphrase, PIN, or pattern, if they choose."_ Not unless `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` was used to allow multiple uses of the key per authentication within a given time frame. Otherwise the documentation states _"Currently, the only means of such authorization is fingerprint authentication"_.

Comment: Not true, when setUserAuthenticationRequired is set to true, then Keystore key is invalidated and key cannot be used anymore. Please refer to documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if "even after the user removed the second fingerprint" is true.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)

setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment (boolean invalidateKey)
By default, invalidateKey is true, so keys that are valid for biometric authentication only are irreversibly invalidated when a new biometric is enrolled, or when all existing biometrics are deleted. That may be changed by calling this method with invalidateKey set to false.